# Interpretation of Rotation Vector Measurements

Tags: android, opencv, math, android-sensors

I use android devices (Xiaomi Mi9-SE (Android 10) & Huawei P10 (Android 9)) to collect movement data from bicycle rides. Hereby, I am measuring i.a the Rotation Vector which describes the rotation of the smartphone to the earth's reference frame ([android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent#sensor.type_rotation_vector:)).

The sensor returns four values, which represent the rotation as a quaternion (w,x,y,z).

In my experiment I recorded a bike ride with two smartphones, which were glued to each other in the same alignment. When I plot the returned values from the Rotation Sensors numerically, they seem to be similar in some phases and dissimilar in others (cf. 1, 2)

However, when in a dissimilar phase (e.g. ~22:12:30h), it seems like the rotations are still somehow the same, but the axis are swapped. I plotted two corresponding rotations (cf. 3, 4). If the x and y axis were swapped and mirrored on the new y, the rotation would become similar. I wonder if this behavior is due to inaccurate/bad sensors or whether I missed something working with quaternions.

Would be really great if someone could tell me, if/where I miss a point here.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unit quaternions used to represent rotations are ambiguous for sign. I.e., q would represent the same rotation as -q. Can you process your q data to ensure consistent signs are used? E.g., ensure the largest magnitude element of the quaternion doesn't change sign from sample to sample by flipping all signs if necessary. Then compare your two data sets. Maybe this will help with the comparison.